# How avoid sending back datas after a reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I try to avoid an alert from the navigator. I use Ajax for my submit form, then I post to another page without refreshing the submit form. I delete an SQL row as a result.

So my First page is a form table with some messages (by ids) I want to delete. If I click on delete button, my form send a POST to the php page to delete the SQL row then I make a reload to update my form table and others elements in my menu.If I click the delete button on the first TR on my table everything works fine. (The Post is sent, datas are received on my second PHP page, the SQL request are executed and my page is reloaded. The Problem : It works only with the first row on my table, if I click the others one, I have an alert from the navigator asking me "This page cannot be refreshed without resending information...)
Why the first works and not the others ?

A part of the code for the form :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY username";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
echo '<form name="'.$form_id_name.'" id="'.$form_id_name.'"  action="'.$action.'" method="POST">';
 echo'<tr>
 <td><center>'.$row[messageid].'</center></td>             
 <td><center>'.addslashes(utf8_decode($row[username])).'</center></td>
 <td><center>'.addslashes(utf8_decode($row[dest])).'</center></td>
 <td><center>'.utf8_decode($row[message]).'</center></td>
 <td><center>'.$row[titre].'</center></td>
 <td><center>'.$row[date].'</center></td>
 <td><center>'.$row[heure].'</center></td>
 <td><center>'.$row[langue].'</center></td>
 <td><center><input type="hidden" name="id"  value="'.$row[messageid].'"/><input type="submit" id="'.$id_button.'" value="X"/></center></td>
 </tr>';
 echo '</form>';
 }



 include('ajax.php');
```

The php page :

```
// some stuffs
$sql = "DELETE FROM messages WHERE messageid = '$messageid'";
$delete=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo '<script>location.reload();</script>';
```

JavaScript example  I'm using ...

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="ajax-form-submit.php" method="POST">
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value ="Ravi"/> <br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value ="Shanker" /> <br/>
Email : <input type="text" name="email" value="xx@xxx.com"/> <br/>
 </form>
 <input type="button"  id="simple-post" value="Run Code" />
 <div id="simple-msg"></div>




 <script>
 $(document).ready(function()
 {


 $("#simple-post").click(function()
 {
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
    $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind();
});

$("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
 });

 });
 </script>
```

I don't understand...

Comment: Hmm... I just noticed that you have a `<from>` as a child of `<tbody>`. This is invalid HTML. Just saying :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here :

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
```

Because if you check, all your forms have the same `id`. Therefore, executing the line above always, and only, submit the first one. Clicking any other form's submit button do not trigger your JavaScript code, but proceed "normally" to perform the post.

From the HTML specification, each element **must** have [a unique `id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html).

#### ** Update (from the comments) **

You don't even need a submit button. These buttons are only triggers to submit the form. Check this HTML :

```
<form id="standardForm" action="/path/to/script.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="secret" value="secretValue" />
   <input type="text" name="userInput" />
</form>

<span class="form-trigger" owns="standardForm">Submit form!</span>
```

and the associated jQuery :

```
$(function() {

    $('span.form-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
        // change 'a,b' into '#a,#b'. We need to do this to convert the HTML
        // attribute value into a jQuery compatible selector.
        var idList = $.map($(this).attr('owns').split(','), function(item) { return '#' + item; }).join(',');

        // submit all the forms associated through the element's 'owns' attribute
        $(idList).submit();

        // do not bubble this event any further.
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

As you can see, I haven't even used an `<a>` element to act as a trigger. Any element may be used, as it is unnecessary for submitting a form. The `<form>` element, however, is required, as this is how the browser can send the input values to the server... through a "form submission".

I hope this clarify things a little.

#### ** Edit **

You can remove the `<form>` elements altogether if you use pure Ajax requests (or XmlHttpRequests) to communicate with the server. The HTML forms simply does it for you, along with the submit button. But using JavaScript, you can do all this manually :

```
$.post('path/to/script.php', { 
    secret: 'secretValue', 
    userInput: 'something'
}).done(function() {
    // optional function called when the request is successful
}).fail(function() {
    // optional function called when the request fails
});
```

The code above does the same thing as the previous example; it submits a form through an HTTP POST to the script `path/to/script.php`. The upside is that it will *not* refresh your page at all.

Comment: Ohh thank you Yannick or merci ! It means one button yields the form except if I use some attributes Id. I could take the Ids from my SQL for that... Thanks again ! I'm gonna try this... Thanks to all !

Comment: Ok I can now delete each rows clicked. I added a class named muButton for all of them in the form, used the id tag to pass the id value. Everything is ok but now I would like to submit the form with an hidden button... Can I do that or am I in the wrong way ? Here's the code I wrote : '$(function(){
    $(".myButton").click(function(){;   
        var myId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        $("#simple-post").submit();      alert($(this).attr('id'));
    });
});'

Comment: @user3281883, answer updated from your last comment.

Comment: I understand Yannick, but after deleting the row I need to submit my form with a very particular value to tell to Ajax not to go to the next php page after submiting. I need to use my php variable $id_button and if not my php page will show up! Not sure if i'm clear !!! lol

Comment: Thanks Yannick ! I didn't know that! It will be useful to me ! I finally found my problem ! I append a hidden input with my value  to my form and simulate a click (to a hidden button (visibility:hidden)) in the form when user clicks on delete button. It Works ! Thanks to all !

Comment: @user3281883, I'm glad you found your problem and that it is now working. Consider getting rid of the whole form altogether and replace it with a manual HTTP request (using jQuery) to submit your request. You don't need the form :)

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer, but you should not reload the page. The whole idea of using ajax is that you can update sections of your page without having to reload the whole page.

What you should do, is check the return value of your ajax request. If the request was fulfilled successfully, you simply remove the row using javascript.

That saves you a request to the server and makes your system a lot more responsive.

By the way, you might run into unforeseen problems because your html is not valid by the look of your php; you should put the form in the last table cell instead of spanning the whole row.

Comment: Yes I did it as well when I came back for tests... You're right form to the last cell table makes more sense ! I 'm doing this refresh because I don't know how to delete a row with jquery and submit (I tried!!!) I know how to refresh others elements in my menu and it works but a table row + submit...

Comment: @user3281883 Probably all you need in your success callback, is something like `$(this).closest('tr').remove();`. But without seeing your javascript, that is just a guess.

Comment: I tried it with an onclick (delete button) but how to submit my form in the same process ? Thanks anyway !!!

Comment: @user3281883 You need to post your javascript yo get a more detailed answer.